# Number Sets in Plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex

Okay, I know how to enter the standard number sets such as Z, Q, R, etc. into LaTeX, but how can I do this in plain TeX? I ask because I can't seem to find it anywhere, and really need them in the document I am currently composing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fonts are called `msbm10` and so on:

```
\newfam\bbbfam
\font\bbbten=msbm10
\font\bbbseven=msbm7
\font\bbbfive=msbm5
\textfont\bbbfam=\bbbten
\scriptfont\bbbfam=\bbbseven
\scriptscriptfont\bbbfam=\bbbfive
\def\bbb{\fam=\bbbfam}

${\bbb Z}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Do you know of any good resources, beyond The TeXbook, that might help me work these problems out for myself in the future? Thanks.

Comment: @DougMoore Probably TeX by Topic can help.